# @font-face problems

Tags: css, font-face

Right now I'm trying desperately to get `@font-face` to work in my website. This is the code I am using right now.

```
@font-face {  
font-family: romeral;  
src: url(fonts/romeral.otf ) format("opentype");  
}
```

And then....

```
h1 {
font-size:2.5em;
font-family:romeral;
}
```

I am using the font Romeral. Here's a link to it: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/02/06/freefont-of-the-week-romeral/

For some reason it just won't work. It won't render the font on the page. I've tried using other fonts like Ripe, and they work. I've made sure I don't have any spelling errors. What I'm wondering is if there is a restriction that some fonts use to stop people from using their fonts with @font-face. Or maybe I've made an obvious mistake in my code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (Enter the names in `""`)

```
@font-face {  
font-family: "romeral";  
src: url("fonts/romeral.otf") format("opentype");  
}
```

Comment: ack!...I had the wrong path. For some reason I thought I was linking it from the main folder but I should have linked it from the css folder. I just added "../" to the beginning of the url and it worked... Crazy me

Comment: In this case the `"…"` don't matter (they only make a difference when using spaces in names).

Answer (score 0):

Does your browser support opentype, you're not using IE are you? In that case you need WEPT fonts.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to generate other font formats for other browsers as well and not just rely on opentype format.  Good tutorial here: [Custom fonts using @font-face](http://www.webistrate.com/css3-custom-fonts-using-font-face/)

Answer (score 0):

I've a solution on this. At first all you have to do is convert your font to .EOT and .WOFF. Then you can use your custom fonts.. Here is a working post for your reference..

http://blog.totusinfo.com/css-html-custom-fonts-on-web-page/